# Get the subfolder as a column while reading multiple parquet files with SparkSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I would like to add a column to each DataFrame loaded from parquet files with SparkSQL, to add a substring of the path to the file, and then make it a single DataFrame.

For example, when loading `.../subfolder1/my_parquet_file1.parquet` and `.../subfolder2/my_parquet_file2.parquet` I want to have the following final DataFrame :

```
col1 | col2 | subfolder
------------------------
aaa  | bbb  | subfolder1
ccc  | ddd  | subfolder1
eee  | fff  | subfolder2
ggg  | hhh  | subfolder2
```

The following code allows to load all the files in a list of paths :

```
sqlContext.read.schema(schema).parquet(paths: _*)
```

But by having directly the final DataFrame I can't add the subfolder depending on where each row came from.

Is there a way to do this without sequentially loading each file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this -

```scala
val df = spark.read
      .parquet(
        getClass.getResource("/parquet/day/day1/part-00000-4ece3595-e410-4301-aefd-431cd1debf91-c000.snappy.parquet")
          .getPath,
        getClass.getResource("/parquet/day/day2/part-00000-4ece3595-e410-4301-aefd-431cd1debf91-c000.snappy.parquet")
          .getPath
      )
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +------+
      * |price |
      * +------+
      * |123.15|
      * |123.15|
      * +------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- price: decimal(5,2) (nullable = true)
      */

    df.withColumn("subfolder", element_at(split(input_file_name(), "/"), -2))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +------+---------+
      * |price |subfolder|
      * +------+---------+
      * |123.15|day1     |
      * |123.15|day2     |
      * +------+---------+
      */
```